# Azure SQL Datasync IP address

Tags: firewall, azure, azure-networking, azure-sql

We have to sync 2 SQL servers located in different clouds under the different tenants.
One in Azure global cloud and another one is in Azure China.
I've created a sync group in global cloud, added Chinese server there and got an error: "Cannot open server requested by the login. Client is not allowed to access the server. To enable access, use the SQL Azure Portal or run sp_set_firewall_rule on the master database to create a firewall rule for this IP address or address range."

I know what this error means. I have to add the SQL Data Sync service ip to the allowed firewall rules.

My problem is that I don't know that ip.
Could someone suggest, how to get Azure SQL Data Sync service IP which is used to access external resources or is there any other way to solve that?

Comment: Did you open the proper ports in the NSG of the China server?

Comment: @Turdie  ports are opened. Server is accessible from the white listed client IPs. The problem is with ip. For a single cloud I could enable "Allow Azure services and resources to access this server", but here we have 2 clouds so it not working.

Comment: You might need to create a tenant to tenant vpn https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network-manager/how-to-configure-cross-tenant-portal

Comment: Yes, VPN is one of the best options here but we can't use it right now.